# Each value of a string to a separate array conversion

Tags: php, string, string-matching

I have a html page contents, that I converted into a string separated by "#".

Example:

```
(2R)-2-hydroxy#250.181#C15H24NO2#2#1#46#1#11#1.1266#1#18#6
```

Is there any way to convert each value of these string to convert into a array?

I need an output like this:

```
$a = (2R)-2-hydroxy    
$b = 250.181    
$c = C15H24NO2   
$d = 2    
$e = 1
//etc...
```

Comment: explode on '#` perhaps? ([explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) But $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, etc doesn't constitute an array, it's just a few unrelated variables

Comment: Are those `$a. $b, $c ..` needed to be the same?

Comment: No, each array $a, $b, $c need to be different so that I can call as per my wish in web page or insert into mysql field wise, I want each value into different array..is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string and loop through the array. Then you can assign each value to a variable, where you can [increment the character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

```
$str = "(2R)-2-hydroxy#250.181#C15H24NO2#2#1#46#1#11#1.1266#1#18#6";
$arr = explode("#", $str);
$start = "a";

foreach($arr as $v) {
    $$start = $v;
    $start++;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to my answer or OP's question. You also don't have to post the comment twice.

Comment: The original, unedited post of OP stated that it was a "one page". One pages are usually built on the query string, so I felt like adding a simple solution for extracting it. Though, after his edit, it may be of no more relevance.

Comment: Hi FoxRider, thank you for your try, but it is just removing the # symbol..I want each value to store in a separate array. So that later I can insert into my database.

Comment: @ombioinfo Does my answer work as you want it or not? Because *I want each value to store in a separate array* confuses me a bit.

Comment: Hello Rizier123, it is not working properly, it is giving output without # thats all.. I want to store each value in separate array. For instance: $val [0]= firstvalue, $val [1]= secondvalue etc.

Comment: @ombioinfo 1. Just do `print_r($arr);` and you will have your output 2. If you just want it in an array, why did you wrote: `$a = xy;` ?

Comment: Thats not which I am looking for, I want each value in a separate array. For instance, $a=firstvalue; $b=second value; etc. That only I wrote in my question, sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: @ombioinfo What? What do you want now? You wrote now 3 different things! One time you wanted it each value in a separated array then you wanted it all in the same array and now you want it again each value assigned to a variable. What do you want now?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I was not clear it may be because I am new to PHP. finally, I want each value assigned to a variable.

Comment: @ombioinfo Then why doesn't my code work: https://eval.in/396188 It exactly does what you want ?!

Comment: It has some typo erro "$$start = $v;". Moreover, it is showing Undefined variable: a in the script file.

Comment: @ombioinfo No it has no typos in it! Otherwise the code wouldn't even run. Also where do you see an undefined error message here: https://eval.in/396188 ?

Comment: I think you are right. I am running it through XAMPP server. Now, I have used '$$start = $v;' instead of '$start = $v;'. But it is not showing anything..How to print the result and check the variables

Comment: @ombioinfo use: `foreach(range("a", chr(97+count($arr)-1)) as $v)
    echo $$v . "\n";` and you see all values.

Comment: I think, we are very close. Now I am getting error: Undefined variable: a, Undefined variable: b

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
$array = explode("#", "(2R)-2-hydroxy#250.181#C15H24NO2#2#1#46#1#11#1.1266#1#18#6");


$array [0] = (2R)-2-hydroxy
$array [1] = 250.181
...
```